# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML is rendering [object object] for image prop

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, rendering, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
     content={
        <span>
          <img className="rounded-circle img_center" 
           src={icon} alt="" />
         </span>
      }
```

if the content is the prop and that has above image content.

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />;
```

This is rendered as [object object], how this can be handled. Also is there a way to use fragments instead of span tag to render **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

Answer (score 0):

in that case you dont need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML but use this library
[jsxt-to-string](https://github.com/grommet/jsx-to-string)

Comment: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    |     property 'stateNode' -> object with constructor 'Home'
    --- property '_reactInternalFiber' closes the circle`

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing HTML you're passing an object (in this case apparently JSX). When an object is rendered directly as HTML it comes out as [object object]. It'll be the className that's causing it to be read as an object rather than just incorrect HTML.

Use a div rather than span.

Comment: i tried passing the classname directly, still its object only. I was using div, but card.text causing issues that div cannot come inside p tag

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa the same still applies, you can't pass JSX into dangerouslySetInnerHTML, it wants HTML (and JS which is part of what makes it dangerous)

Comment: is <img /> tag not html?

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa it is, but src={avatar} isn't, nor is className={['avatar', 'rounded-circle'].join(' ')}. Those are JSX forms

Comment: `content={
            <span>
              <img className="rounded-circle img_center" src={icon} alt="" />
            </span>
          }`

Even this doesnt work, tried simplifiying at my best

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa for HTML it's class not className and you can't pass the src as a variable. I think dangerouslySetInnerHTML isn't what you want. What you need is to just handle the image directly.

Comment: i am trying to work on animated preloaders as a placeholder for text and image contents. tText renders fine but not image. What you mean to handle image directly here?

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa  dangerouslySetInnerHTML isn't the solution to your problem. It will not do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa personally I use a placeholder class that's a pure css infinitely rotating object.